# Ajax HTTP request changes JSON with array in request body

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, httpresponse

The JSON response body of the HTTP request is being distorted on the server side. It has one key and its element is an array. This is my HTTP request using jQuery ajax:

```
function dbInsert(event_arr) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:5000/insertdata",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(event_arr),
        success: function(events) {
            console.log("TestInsert was successfully executed");
        },
        error: function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

When I print JSON.stringify(event_arr) to console, this is what it looks like:

```
{"results": [{"event_client": "name1","event_date": "date1"}, {"event_client": "name2", "event_date": "date2"}]}
```

Then, on the server side, here are my various attempts at understanding the response body and playing around with the JSON format:

```
// returns [object, Object], cannot be passed into JSON.parse
console.log(request.body);

var temp = JSON.stringify(request.body); 
var temp2 = JSON.parse(temp); 

// prints {"{\"results\":":{"{\"event_name\":\"name1\",\"event_date\":\"date1\"},{\"event_name\":\"name2\",\"event_date\":\"date2\"}":""}}
console.log(temp);

// prints { '{"results":': { '{"event_name":"name1","event_date":"date1"},{"event_name":"name2","event_date":"date2"}': '' } }
console.log(temp2);
```

The JSON.stringify() that was called in my dbInsert() seems to mess up how the JSON is read, and I don't how to work around this internal formatting error!

Comment: You need to set: **`contentType: "application/json"`**, in your **`$.ajax({})`** function and check again what you get in server side.

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you so much, that was such a simple fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set: `contentType: "application/json"`, in your `$.ajax({})` function.

Something like this:

```
function dbInsert(event_arr) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:5000/insertdata",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(event_arr),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(events) {
      console.log("TestInsert was successfully executed");
    },
    error: function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```